# ExtJS slider thumb will disappear after click the bar

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs5, extjs-mvc

Hi I have a `xtype: slider`. The thumb will disappear after I click the bar.

I tried to work on sencha fiddle but it works fine.

[fiddle sample](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/11uf)

However the bug will happen in my website

[myweb](http://ract1436.myweb.hinet.net/samplemvc/)

I do nothing special for my slider object so I have no idea.

```
xtype: 'slider',
width: 200,
value: 0,
increment: 10,
minValue: 0,
maxValue: 100,
```

**[UPDATE]**

I have updated the fiddle and my website.

There are three kind of thumbs.

1. fiddle 5.0.1 default image

[image]

2. my 5.0.1 default image

[image]

3. my custom image

[image]

When I click the progress bar the 2,3 will disappear.

Whether I have to link the big size image like 1? Or any other way can fix this problem?

Comment: Do you use exactly the same ExtJS version as in the fiddle sample?

Comment: Yes. I have checked the ext-all.js. The version is 5.0.1.1255

Answer (score 0):

You used a different background image, which is too small.

- [From your fiddle](https://extjs.cachefly.net/ext/gpl/5.0.1/packages/ext-theme-crisp/build/resources/images/slider/slider-thumb.png)
- [From your site](http://ract1436.myweb.hinet.net/samplemvc/jslibs/ext-5.0.1/resources/css/images/slider/slider-thumb.png)

Comment: I tried to replace the different size thumb image and fix the problem. If I want to replace the thumb to my custom image the bug is still there.

Comment: Well, you did not replace it. I don't know what you did, but you did not replace the image.

Comment: Hi Alexander. I have updated the fiddle and my website. Please give me some suggestions. Thank you.